# Selecting the key from a dictionary in python

Tags: python

```
new = {key: value_keys[key] for key in ['text', 'lang']}
```

So I need someone to clarify why I have to put `key: value_keys[key]` In this manner to extract the keys from the dictionary.

Next, I need to know why I can't select specific keys from this code `value_keys.keys()`.

Comment: `value_keys[key]` doesn't extract the keys, it extracts the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code `new = {key: value_keys[key] for key in ['text', 'lang']}`  is doing the same as this code:

```
for key in ['text', 'lang']:
   new[key] = value_keys[key]
```

You are essentially iterating over each key in `value_keys` and assigning the same key and the same value to a new dictionary called `new`.

`value_keys[key]` returns the value of `key` in the dictionary `value_keys`.

**Answer 1)**

> So I need someone to clarify why I have to put `key: value_keys[key]` In this manner to extract the keys from the dictionary.

You do not have to put `key: value_keys[key]` in that manner to extract the keys from the dictionary. You can also use for loops:

```
for key in value_keys
   print(key)
```

or

```
for key in value_keys.keys()
   print(key)
```

[Python How to iterate through dictionary](https://realpython.com/iterate-through-dictionary-python/)

**Answer 2)**

> Next, I need to know why I can't select specific keys from this code `value_keys.keys()`.

`value_keys.keys()` is returning a list of all the keys in the `value_keys` dictionary, you can select a specific key from the list by iterating through the list of all keys and checking if the key meets a condition (in this example I chose to select the key if it was called 'text'):

```
for key in value_keys.keys():
   if(key == "text"):
      print(key)
```

If you just want to check whether or not a key is in a dictionary you can use:

```
if key in value_keys:
   #code to execute if the key is in the dictionary
else:
   #code to execute if the key is not in the dictionary
```

[Python check if key exists in dictionary](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-check-if-a-key-exists-in-a-python-dictionary)